# Scrolling text that is being updated in a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

Im using a NSTimer to update the text in a UITextView, also I need this UITextView to scroll down if the text doesnt fit anymore the size of the UITextView.
I've looked for the answer, but it scrolls too slow, the text is getting updated but you can't see it anymore because it's scrolling to slow.

This is the function that is called everytime the NSTimer fires, which is every 0.05 seconds:

```
- (void)addLetters{
     times++;
     self.message.text = [message1 substringToIndex:times];

    [self.message scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([self.message.text length] -1, 1)];

    if(times == MAX){
       [temp invalidate];
       temp = nil;
    }
}
```

Each time it execites Im adding a letter from the string `message1` to the UITextView `self.message`

Thanks

Comment: have u decreased the delay further & checked.?

Comment: Yes, and it scrolls a bit more, but the text gets updated really slow and it takes too long to be updated.
Why is this? Scrolling the uitextview is such a time consuming method that it doesnt have time to do it before the NSTimer fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `[textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, textView.contentSize.height-1, 1, 1) animated:NO];`

It wont animate the jump but since you call it so many times maybe outcome will satisfy you.